# I need to add names and ages to an arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I am new to programming so my question is how would I add the following data to an arraylist

```
Fred    21
Jo  43
Zoe 37
```

I have found that when I do

```
ArrayList<String> namearray_list=new ArrayList<String>(); 
namearray_list.add("Fred");
```

I can't add the age because that is an integer

I looked at a similar question on this site but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Well it sounds like what you really want is a `Person` class or something similar - to hold both a name and an age. Then you can have a `List<Person>`.

Comment: ah yes I have been asked to create a data class and have done so but I still am lost

Comment: Well show us what you've done then, and be specific about the problem you still face.

Comment: @ntalbs this edit is wrong -- you shouldn't really fix errors in the code, that the user is actually asking about.

Comment: @djechlin Why do you believe that my edit is wrong. I just reformatted to look nicer, not edit the code itself. Could you let me know what I did wrong?

Comment: @ntalbs http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41491213/revisions "ArrayList" became "ArrayList<String>" in that edit.

Answer (score 2):

An `ArrayList` would hold exactly one type of data. As it stands you have a *compiler warning* that you need to fix, which is that `ArrayList` needs to specify a type, either `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<Integer>` would be appropriate in this case. Then what you are trying to do is wrong, would be more obvious.

Your options are:

- Write a `Person` class with `name` and `age`
- Force `age` to be a string, e.g. `"" + 21` (this would be confusing and poor design though)
- Use two `ArrayList`, one for each data type

Comment: Thanks for your help how would I go about doing the first option

Comment: @Rhp12321 You need to find a textbook or tutorials or some other instruction -- your question isn't a great fit for SO in the first place but I gave you a start. I'm not really in this to teach programming from the ground up.

Comment: Hey thanks man I'll give a shot at one of your options.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class called Person to store name and age.

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;

    Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

then create a new object and add it to your list:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
people.add(new Person("Fred", 21));
people.add(new Person("Jo", 43));
people.add(new Person("Zoe", 37));
```

Comment: Thanks for spoon feeding someone code and cheating them out of the opportunity to create it themself.

Comment: I'm not going to vote, but I'm kind of opposed to handing complete solutions to people who are basically asking for programming tutorials, or just solutions to their homework problem for class or self-study in lieu of programming tutorials.

Comment: @djechlin: you should vote. This behavior should not be encouraged.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tend to avoid downvoting if 1) I have a competing answer or 2) I left a constructive enough comment (that either qualifies the answer or gives a chance to improve it). And certainly our two comments are suggestions for anyone else who looks. I think *my* answer is iffy but stopping short of "hand me teh codez" is a big difference.

Comment: @djechlin: I have no qualms about up-voting or down-voting answers to questions that I've also answered, depending on the quality of the answer. This one is quite obviously terrible. Yours I've up-voted OTH.

Comment: HI guys I understand your issues but I really did try searching for answers to the question but I couldn't get anything to work. I truly am sorry.

Comment: @Rhp12321: the answer is in your Java textbook -- this is nothing but first 1-2 chapter stuff. You should read that first.